# How to restart Android Service when it is killed from Settings

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android application that in `onCreate` method of Main ACtivity starts a Background Service.

This is a lightweight Service and I want to keep it running all the time. So , I return `START_STCKY` in `onStartCommand()` method of Service.

When App is launched and the service starts running,in case,if Only Running Service is killed from the Settings ,and then if App is relaunched ,the `onCreate` method of app is not called and Service is not restarted.

If I start my Service in onResume() method of Activity , it does not seem to be  a good practice to keep on checking if my Service is running or not.

How to handle this situation? I want that when the service is killed and app is relaunched , even though the app was running in background, the service should be restarted.

Comment: I think just calling startService() should do it. If the service is already running, nothing will happen.

Comment: What is `onCreate method of app`? And startService() can do you required task if I understood your problem

Comment: flag, on starting the service set a flag, set it true, when service gets stopped, set it false, verify again and start !

Comment: that is ok but in which ACtivity life cycle call back I should check this, I am starting my service in on create , if along with service app is also killed,there is no problem but if only service is kiled ,onCreate of Activity is not called and service is nt restarted?

Comment: in onCreate() and in onResume();

Comment: checking for flag all the time in onResume does not seem to be efficient

Comment: if the app is in background i.e paused() then we can only check the state of service through onResume.. as onStart() and onCreate() will never be called.

Comment: Checking in onResume() is fine, but onResume() is called multiple times interacting with the Application.Will that be a good soluion?

Comment: of course there might me a better solution, its a small suggestion from my side !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using startService ,I am using BindService , I bind the  Service in `onCreate` of the application and unbind it in `onTerminate` of application.

This keeps running my service all the time till the app is running and User is not given any option in App Manager to kill Running Services in my App.